# Emacs Lisp function, that write-region to file and delete it

Tags: emacs, lisp, buffer, elisp, region

I want to write a ELisp function that will:
append current region to a new file (it is already written in ELisp standard library and it is called write-region) and then open this file as new buffer in background so I can edit it later.

but I also want the current selected region to be deleted.

I want to do something like this:

```
(defun write-region-delete-and-open(start end filename)
  "function takes current region, and writes it to specified file"
  (interactive "r\nsFilename: ")
  (write-region start end filename t)
  (kill-region start end))
```

But It isn't working as I assume. When I cut the region, it always kills all after that region in buffer. I also want to use (ido-find-file) to select file to write a buffet to. I completely have no idea how to open created file in background. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `ido-find-file`, change the interactive specification for the `filename` argument to `F`.  That is:

```
(interactive "r\nFFilename: ")
```

That's assuming you're already using ido for opening other files, as by `(ido-mode 1)` in your `.emacs` file.

The function to open a file in the background, by which I assume you mean to open a file without displaying it immediately, is called `find-file-noselect`.

I don't know why the entire buffer after the region would be killed by that call to `kill-region`; I don't see that happen when I use your code.

Comment: Ok, now everythings works great, even the killing region :) Thanks a lot.